# How to Sharpen a PDF Drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf, includegraphics, tikz-pic

The following [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_of_God#/media/File:Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry_Fig398.png) image is in the public domain:

[image]

Using `\includegraphics`, I incorporated the image into some LaTeX code, edited out the border, and saved the remaining portion as a PDF.

Now, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\node at (0,8){I would like to darken this sentence.};

\node at (0,7){I would like to darken this sentence.};
\node at (0,7){I would like to darken this sentence.};
\node at (0,7){I would like to darken this sentence.};
\node at (0,7){I would like to darken this sentence.};
\node at (0,7){I would like to darken this sentence.};

\node at (0,5.5){But now I would like to darken this IMAGE:};

\node at (0,-1){\includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0,page=2]{clipping.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I would like to sharpen (darken) the image; unfortunately, since it is a PDF, I cannot do this in a manner analogous to the way I was able to darken up one of the sentences in the code.

QUESTION: How may I sharpen (darken) a PDF image (such as this one) using LaTeX?

Thank you.

Comment: don't use latex, use a bitmap editing tool gimp or imagemagic or whatever you prefer. latex has difficulties even including a png (latex+dvips can not do so) editing it in anything but the most simple ways isn't really an option

Comment: note you can make the text darker in much better ways than multiple overprinting by modifying the font rendering

Comment: Drawing something multiple times the same place does not darken it. I might appear darker on the screen, but that is dependent on the viewer and just an artefact because of beed through of color when calculating e.g. antialiasing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, there are better ways for darkening text I'm sure, but I opted for this approach to convey the idea that something that "works" for text does not for a PDF---which helped me, I thought, to introduce the question.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: For every screw there is a perfect screwdriver and trying to screw it with another tool is always the wrong decision.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As David writes, this is best done in a bitmap editor. If you really want, you can use a blend like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){\includegraphics{sheep.jpg}};
\begin{scope}[blend mode=color burn, yshift=-16cm]
\foreach \a in {0,60,...,300}
\node at (\a:0.5pt){\includegraphics{sheep.jpg}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: One light sheep and below one darkened sheep]

Comment: Many thanks, once again, for a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, one may do a raster-to-vector conversion (PNG->PDF).   Let me know if you want the resulting PDF.
[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for this post; if you can attach the PDF, I would appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: No. I can't attach the PDF.  Just images. You can download the PDF from this link: https://filesender.fccn.pt/?s=download&token=7a93dbd1-8c2d-4413-bdc2-932d610baa65

Comment: I got it. Many thanks.